# Using CCEaseOut together with CCSequence?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite, ccaction

I want my action have an effect ease in / ease out, but I already have CCSequence. If I put CCEaseOut in front of my code, movement become weird.
Is it possible to make CCEaseOut/CCEaseIn with CCSequence ? 
Here is my code :

```
[player runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1],
                            [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:2 opacity:255],
                            [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1],
                            [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:7 opacity:0],nil]];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use CCEase* with most actions but not the CCSequence action directly. You can however wrap one of the actions inside the sequence into a CCEase* action.